# Java AmazonS3Client : big size file upload is taking very log/hung

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to **upload 50-60 MB sized file to aws s3 bucket** with the code below. The code, below, is working. However, upload is slow and getting stuck ( not uploading/just hung) sometimes. Using **progressListener**, noticed that it is uploading **8 bytes at a time**. Hence my suspect is when our clients use our application, getting timed out waiting for about 6000 uploads to finish. Was wondering **if there is a way to increase upload size** keeping the s3client (**AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2**) same as encryption part is very important for us as well.

```
public boolean uploadStreamToS3(String remoteId, InputStream is, long length) {
    AmazonFileTransfer amazonInstance = AmazonFileTransfer.getInstance();
    AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 encryptedS3client = amazonInstance.getClientInstance();
    
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        // Set object metadata
        ObjectMetadata om = new ObjectMetadata();
        om.setContentLength(length);

        // Prepare to upload the file
        PutObjectRequest s3UploeadRequest = new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, remoteId, is, om);
        ProgressListener progressListener = progressEvent -> log.info("====> Transferred bytes for remote Id " + remoteId + " : " + progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
        
        //Upload the file
        s3UploeadRequest.setGeneralProgressListener(progressListener);
        encryptedS3client.putObject(s3UploeadRequest);

    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        log.error("uploadStreamToAWS - AmazonClientException " + remoteId + " error " + ace);
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("uploadStreamToAWS - Error putting object " + remoteId + " error " + e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**encryptedS3client** is created this way :

```
public static AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 createAmazonS3Client(final String secretKey,
                                                            final String accessKey,
                                                            final String keystoreLocation,
                                                            final char[] keyStorePassword,
                                                            final char[] keyPassword,
                                                            final String publicKeyLocation) {
    KeyPair myKeyPair = null;
    try {
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(publicKeyLocation);
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(keystoreLocation, keyStorePassword, keyPassword, "awsKeys");
        myKeyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("can't build key pair", e);
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if (accessKey == null) {
            log.error("accessKey is null");
            return null;
        }
        if (secretKey == null) {
            log.error("createAmazonS3Client secretKey is null");
            return null;
        }

        CryptoConfigurationV2 cryptoConfigV2 = new CryptoConfigurationV2(CryptoMode.AuthenticatedEncryption);
        
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(myKeyPair);
        AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 client = (AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2) AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2Builder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                        Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("S3_ENDPOINT")).orElse("https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"),
                        Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")).orElse("us-west-1")))
                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withCryptoConfiguration(cryptoConfigV2)
                .withEncryptionMaterialsProvider(new StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider(encryptionMaterials))
                .build();
        return client;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("exception occurred", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please let me know should provide any more clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you uploading a 50MB file or 6000 files or 50MB * 6000 files?

Comment: One file of 50 MB. I am seeing about 6000 api calls per file to upload the full file. Looks like each time only 8 bytes is getting uploaded

Comment: AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 is still a V1 library just to let you know. If you want to work with latest S3 API - look at using AWS SDK for Java V2. The Client object is software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client